# Signature verification failed: invalid padding - Python flask-saml2

Tags: python, xml, flask, single-sign-on, saml

In Python SSO, I'm using **flask-saml2** library.
I make 'Sign Response As Required' as True and renewal the .pem files.
After that,I am getting following error,

```
{"message":"Signature verification failed: invalid padding"}
```

and code is:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
        stateInfo = request.cookies.get('state')
        clientId = request.cookies.get('clientCode')
        if sp.is_user_logged_in():
            auth_data = sp.get_auth_data_in_session()
            
            profileKey = {
                'user_id': auth_data.nameid
            }

        else:
            return redirect(url_for('invalid'))
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Have you ensured that the `.pem` file format matches the requirement for both your SAML SP and IdP? The response from your IdP must also match what SP expects to receive.